# How to properly type decorator and decorated function?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-decorators, python-typing

I have a decorator which should catch errors from the request:

```
def catch_request_errors(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):  # -> Optional[Dict]
        try:
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            capture_message(str(e), level='error')
            errors = {'error': str(e)}
            return errors

        if not response.ok:
            capture_message(response.text, level='error')
            errors = {'error': str(response.text)}
            return errors

        return None

    return inner_function
```

The decorator itself returns *Optional[Dict]* - when error occurs should return {'error': 'error_msg_here'} or None if there are no errors.

Here is my decorated function, which actually returns **Response** without decorator, but with decorator it returns **Optional[Dict]**:

```
@catch_request_errors
def make_request(self, url: str, data: Dict): # -> Optional[Dict]
    return requests.post(url, data)  # but there is actually -> Response
```

I had to "hard type" like that to bamboozle my IDE, but how should I do it properly?

```
request_errors = self.make_request(settings.DOCUMENT_GENERATOR_URL, data)  # type: Optional[Dict]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get it to work in just the pycharm IDE to not display the error, or are you using a type checker such as mypy?

Comment: just IDE to not display the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat similar solution like in [subprocess.Popen.comunicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

```py
def catch_request_errors(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
        response = None
        errors = None
        try:
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            capture_message(str(e), level='error')
            errors = {'error': str(e)}

        if response is not None and not response.ok:
            capture_message(response.text, level='error')
            errors = {'error': str(response.text)}

        return response, errors

    return inner_function
```

```py
@catch_request_errors
def make_request(self, url, data):
    return requests.post(url, data)
```

```py
response, errors = make_request(URL, DATA)
if errors is not None:
    # handle errors
else:
    # code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having similar problem, I am posting my solution with types, thanks to @woblob

Decorator:

```
def catch_request_errors(func: Callable[[str, Dict], Response]) -> Callable[[Tuple[Any], Dict[str, Any]],
                                                                            Tuple[Response, Optional[Dict]]]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner_function(*args, **kwargs) -> Tuple[Response, Optional[Dict]]:
        response = None
        errors = None
        try:
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            capture_message(str(e), level='error')
            errors = {'error': str(e)}

        if response and not response.ok:
            capture_message(response.text, level='error')
            errors = {'error': str(response.text)}

        return response, errors

    return inner_function
```

```
@catch_request_errors
def make_request(self, url: str, data: Dict) -> Response:
    return requests.post(url, data)
```

```
response, errors = self.make_request(settings.DOCUMENT_GENERATOR_URL, data)
```